# Iptables time-based rules having no effect - Gateway with 2 NICs

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, time, gateway

I have a network with the following topology:
- WAN Modem with NIC facing the gateway: 192.168.0.1
- Ubuntu 14.04 gateway with two NICs:
  1) Eth0 (facing the modem): 192.168.0.201
  2) Eth1 (facing the LAN): 10.0.0.1

I am trying to limit access to the Internet and to the LAN (from the Internet) by day and time of day using *iptables*, but the rules seem to have no effect what-so-ever.

In rc.local, I have the following setup:

```
++#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
# turning on address verification
echo -n "Enabling source address verification..."
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
echo "done"

    #just for the sake of turning the networks off and on... not sure if it would work turning them back on only at the end of script ? -- Also flushing NICs
    ip addr flush eth0;
    ip addr flush eth1;
    ifconfig eth0 down;
    ifconfig eth1 down;
    ifconfig lo down;
    ifconfig lo up;
    ifconfig eth0 up;
    ifconfig eth1 up;
    ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.201 netmask 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
    #routing table check up :
    route add 127.0.0.1 dev lo;
    route add -net 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo;
    route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1;
    route add -net 192.168.0.0/8 dev eth0;
    route add default gw 192.168.0.1;
    # turn fowarding off while configuring iptables :
    sysctl net/ipv4/ip_forward=0
    iptables -F
    iptables -X
    iptables -P INPUT DROP
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t nat -X
    iptables -t mangle -F
    iptables -t mangle -X
    #and on again once the policies are set
    sysctl net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
    #limiting LAN clients
    iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.74 -m time --timestart 20:00 --timestop 10:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.228 -m time --timestart 20:00 --timestop 10:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.121 -m time --timestart 20:00 --timestop 10:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.221 -m time --timestart 20:00 --timestop 10:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.2 -m time --timestart 10:00 --timestop 20:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
    #block IPs
    iptables -A INPUT -s 173.194.45.189 -j DROP
    iptables -A INPUT -s 208.92.53.87 -j DROP
    #masquerade on wan card :
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    #accept all packets in lo and protect against spoofing :
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i !lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j LOG
    iptables -A INPUT -i !lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
    iptables -A FORWARD -i !lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j LOG
    iptables -A FORWARD -i !lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
    #accept only established input but all output on WAN card
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT 
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
    #just forget the invalid packets :
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j LOG
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    #not sure whether to put this before or after spoofing protection ?
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
    #against spoofing on LAN card input :
    iptables -A INPUT -i !eth1 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j LOG
    iptables -A INPUT -i !eth1 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
exit 0
```

Listing the rules with *iptables -L* I get:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  173.194.45.189       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  208.92.53.87         anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:sunrpc
ACCEPT     udp  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:sunrpc
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere             LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 
LOG        all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere             LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The time-based rules isn't there. Can anybody see why? Note: It is a day and time of day where the following rule should be active:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.2 -m time --timestart 10:00 --timestop 20:00 --days Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
```

Comment: Always use `-v` when listing iptables rules, or you will not see the complete rule set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For days option, use **`--weekdays`** instead of **`--days`** as shown below

```
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.2 -m time --timestart 10:00 --timestop 20:00 --weekdays Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j DROP
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 328 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.2             TIME from 10:00:00 to 20:00:00 on Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sun UTC

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: this rule does not work anymore

Comment: And it's still not working on Ubuntu 16.04 - had to resort to cron.